How to make elements stick to different scrollable containers for different scroll directions?
I have a long and wide table inside a width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; container, and I'm trying to achieve the following at the same time:

make the header row stick to the viewport's top edge;
make the first column stick to the container's left edge.

Here's an extremely simplified example of the page I have: codepen.
Sometimes the viewport can be wide enough, but there are too many rows, so the vertical scroll appears:

Sometimes the table is too wide for the given viewport, so the horizontal scroll appears:

Sometimes both vertical and horizontal scroll can happen at the same time.

I can easily make the first column stick to the left edge by the following styles:
th:first-child, 
td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

However, I failed to make the header row sticky to the top edge without breaking the basic layout:
.container {
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */ /* no way! */
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

How can I overcome this problem? Thanks for any ideas.
I obviously can not abandon the container-based horizontal scroll in favour of the viewport scroll because then the content above the table will also be scrollable.

Could you please elaborate on "breaking the basic layout"? Adding sticky to both first row and column works for me (with z-index adjustment for the top left cell.)

@SyndRain Could you please share a modified codepen which works for you? I just tried again and I have only the column sticky, the header is just scrolled away to the top: https://codepen.io/shau-kote/pen/VwJdMjg

@SyndRain By "breaking the basic layout" I mean that I had to remove the overflow-x: auto; property and such a change causes the content above the table to also be scrollable when the table is too wide.

Using sticky on both the first row and column is working. The header didn't scroll up. It's just being covered by the tbody rows.
You can adjust the z-index of the top-left cell to prevent it being covered by others.


.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

td {
  background: white;
}

th {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.container th {
  &:first-child {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
}

.container td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: -1px;
}
<h1>
  HR DB (just example)
</h1>

<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employee ID</th>
        <th>Full Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP001</td>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>Marketing</td>
        <td>Marketing Manager</td>
        <td>2020-03-15</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP002</td>
        <td>Emma Johnson</td>
        <td>Human Resources</td>
        <td>HR Specialist</td>
        <td>2019-11-02</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP003</td>
        <td>Michael Brown</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>Senior Developer</td>
        <td>2018-07-20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP004</td>
        <td>Sarah Davis</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>Sales Representative</td>
        <td>2021-01-10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP005</td>
        <td>David Wilson</td>
        <td>Finance</td>
        <td>Financial Analyst</td>
        <td>2020-09-05</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP006</td>
        <td>Jennifer Lee</td>
        <td>Customer Service</td>
        <td>Customer Support Manager</td>
        <td>2019-04-18</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP007</td>
        <td>Robert Taylor</td>
        <td>Operations</td>
        <td>Operations Coordinator</td>
        <td>2020-11-30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP008</td>
        <td>Lisa Anderson</td>
        <td>Marketing</td>
        <td>Content Writer</td>
        <td>2021-06-22</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP009</td>
        <td>Daniel Martinez</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>Network Administrator</td>
        <td>2018-12-01</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP010</td>
        <td>Emily White</td>
        <td>Human Resources</td>
        <td>Recruitment Specialist</td>
        <td>2020-02-14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP011</td>
        <td>Christopher Clark</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>Account Manager</td>
        <td>2019-08-07</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP012</td>
        <td>Olivia Harris</td>
        <td>Finance</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>2021-03-29</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP013</td>
        <td>William Turner</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>2020-07-11</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP014</td>
        <td>Sophia Rodriguez</td>
        <td>Marketing</td>
        <td>Digital Marketing Specialist</td>
        <td>2019-10-05</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP015</td>
        <td>James Nelson</td>
        <td>Operations</td>
        <td>Logistics Manager</td>
        <td>2018-05-19</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP016</td>
        <td>Ava Thompson</td>
        <td>Customer Service</td>
        <td>Customer Support Representative</td>
        <td>2021-09-03</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP017</td>
        <td>Alexander Scott</td>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td>Business Development Manager</td>
        <td>2020-01-25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP018</td>
        <td>Mia Green</td>
        <td>Human Resources</td>
        <td>Training Coordinator</td>
        <td>2019-06-14</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP019</td>
        <td>Ethan Baker</td>
        <td>IT</td>
        <td>Data Analyst</td>
        <td>2021-04-07</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>EMP020</td>
        <td>Isabella King</td>
        <td>Finance</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>2018-09-22</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




You made a very good point about z-index, but as I outlined in the question, I need to make the header row stick to the viewport's top edge, so the h1 block should be scrollable.

@shau-kote Adding position:fixed to the container as well can have it stick to the viewport. However, you've added max-height:100vh on the container, which means it either overlaps the h1 when positioned at the very top, or could overflow the viewport if not positioned at the very top. Could you please clarify what you actually want?
